# How do I avoid exceeding Discord API rate limits in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, rate-limiting

I'm making a Discord bot and I recently got a temporary API ban because I got rate limited. These bans are from calling the API too frequently, and I've tried putting cooldowns on the commands using-

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def ...
```

However, even if someone uses a command while it is on cooldown, it still counts as a request to the API.

Is there a way I could avoid this using discord.py?

Comment: It appears that the only way to get "banned" is by [sending invalid requests](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#invalid-request-limit-aka-cloudflare-bans), and anything else is just a normal rate-limit that is automatically handled by the Discord API. Can you check out the debug log to see what requests your bot is sending?

Comment: `discord.py` is supposed to handle rate limits for you. Are you doing anything else in your code that could be bypassing this?

Comment: discord.py handles ratelimits per endpoint, but it does not handle the global ratelimit (which is 50 requests per second) @Benjin

Comment: If you’re using a host like repl.it you should really consider changing it. They use a shared IP for everything running on the service, if someone is running a bot on their service and gets banned, everyone on that IP will be banned. **Including you.**

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński

Well, for me replit is pretty much my only option.
I don't own a computer and so I have to code on mobile. What else can I use that would allow me to code on mobile and easily restart my bot whenever I needed. What other thing has free hosting and keeps your bot always on?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you dont have to many background commands or using api stuff like mass banning etc that could flag your account.